# Mysql equal vs greater than(less than) performance difference

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a performance difference in Mysql for big dataset while using equals or greater than in where clause.

I can run following two queries for same purpose.

`select * from My_Table where MY_Field > 100;` // 100 is old value

or

```
select * from MY_Table where MY_Field = 101;
```

It is known value of My_Field if greater than 100 will 101.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Just curious, define "big"? Hundreds of millions?

Comment: Yes. Not the definition of big, but yes, here it is hundreds of millions.

Answer (score 3):

If `MY_Field` is covered with index then the difference in searching values in index is not big. This is true until the result set is about 30% of the total number rows in a table.

But, for each record found in index mysql need to perform seek on data file to find the appropriate row (since you have `SELECT *`).

So - in your case if you know the specific field value it must be better to use `=`.

Comment: MY_Field is of course indexed. Resultset will be around 1-50% of the total in most scenarios.  Select * was to make query look simple here, but yes I do select most of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the index type on this particular column: BTREE is good when you search in ranges, HASH is good when you search for equation

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize query if you know only one result is going to be fetched use LIMIT 1

```
select * from MY_Table where MY_Field = 101 LIMIT 1;
```

which is better as while executing if it finds a single row matching result mysql will stop execution

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous answer, resultset will be around 1-50% of the total in most scenarios, i.e. 1-50% of table having millions of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `MY_Field = 101` because mysql will perform `ref` access type which means index will be compared with reference value, which is faster that `range` in case `MY_Field > 100` which means mysql will compare range values in index.

You can check it in `type` field in `explain` for your query.